# How can I keep all columns in a dataframe, plus add groupby, and sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with 5 fields.  I want to copy 2 fields from this into a new data frame.  This works fine.  `df1 = df[['task_id','duration']]`

Now in this df1, when I try to group by `task_id` and sum `duration`, the `task_id` field drops off.

Before (what I have now).

[image]

After (what I'm trying to achieve).
[image]

So, for instance, I'm trying this:

```
df1['total'] = df1.groupby(['task_id'])['duration'].sum()
```

The result is:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I don't know why I can't just sum the values in a column and group by unique IDs in another column.  Basically, all I want to do is preserve the original two columns (`['task_id', 'duration']`), sum `duration`, and calculate a percentage of `duration` in a new column named `pct`.  This seems like a very simple thing but I can't get anything working.  How can I get this straightened out?

Comment: Add some data sample, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will take care of having the columns retained and getting the sum.

```
df[['task_id', 'duration']].groupby(['task_id', 'duration']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

Comment: I am hoping you will calculate `pct` by your own, if not..let me know..i will extend the code!!

Comment: I just updated my original post.  I added a before and after screen shot.  Again, i have a data frame with several fields.  I just want to move to into a new data frame, group by the 'task_id' sum the 'duration', and calculate the relative percentage of each duration in a third column.  I looked for some samples of how to do this online.  I found some interesting things, but nothing that does what I want.   It seems like a pretty simple thing.  I just can't seem to get it working quite right.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup:**

```
X = np.random.choice([0,1,2], 20)
Y = np.random.uniform(2,10,20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'task_id':X, 'duration':Y})
```

**Calculate pct:**

```
df = pd.merge(df, df.groupby('task_id').agg(sum).reset_index(), on='task_id')
df['pct'] = df['duration_x'].divide(df['duration_y'])*100
df.drop('duration_y', axis=1) # Drops sum duration, remove this line if you want to see it.
```

Result:

```
     duration_x  task_id        pct
0     8.751517        0  58.017921
1     6.332645        0  41.982079
2     8.828693        1   9.865355
3     2.611285        1   2.917901
4     5.806709        1   6.488531
5     8.045490        1   8.990189
6     6.285593        1   7.023645
7     7.932952        1   8.864436
8     7.440938        1   8.314650
9     7.272948        1   8.126935
10    9.162262        1  10.238092
11    7.834692        1   8.754639
12    7.989057        1   8.927129
13    3.795571        1   4.241246
14    6.485703        1   7.247252
15    5.858985        2  21.396850
16    9.024650        2  32.957771
17    3.885288        2  14.188966
18    5.794491        2  21.161322
19    2.819049        2  10.295091
```

`disclaimer`: All data is randomly generated in setup, however, calculations are straightforward and should be correct for any case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got everything working in the following way.

```
# group by and sum durations
df1 = df1.groupby('task_id', as_index=False).agg({'duration': 'sum'})
list(df1)

# find each task_id as relative percentage of whole
df1['pct'] = df1['duration']/(df1['duration'].sum())
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```